# WooCommerce goes server load and server memory used high

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, server

I have a site in my server with WordPress v4.8.3 and WooCommerce v3.2.3.

I noticed that this particular website use too much memory and server CPU.

I starting disable, one by one, the WordPress plugins to check if I have any changes.

I found that when WooCommerce plugin is on, the server load goes to 15% and memory use up to 55% and all sites in this server are goes slower, when the the WooCommerce is offline the server load goes to 1.9% - 3.3% and memory use to 10%.

In this server we have over 20 sites with WordPress and WooCommerce but only this website use memory and CPU so hard...
And it's not the most popular site, traffic is not that intense

server CPU: 8 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1270 v3 @ 3.50GHz
server Memory: 34603008k
system information: Linux 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64

Any idea which way to search?

Comment: Do you see the same issue with all other plugins deactivated? - WooCommerce *is* pretty heavy on it's own, but I usually see the most extreme issues in *combination* with other (poorly written) extensions like for example a POS plugin - recently I had one that had absolutely horrible performance when combined with a MailChimp integration plugin. Naturally disabling WooCommerce also disables most plugins that rely on it / extend it... so the fact that disabling WooCommerce solves the issue doesn't necessarily mean that WooCommerce itself is causing it.

Comment: Yes i disable the plugins, one by one, but the WooCommerce last. I had the same things, i disable the bank bridge plugin first, WooCommerce Advanced Shipping plugin, WooCommerce Enhanced Ecommerce Analytics Integration with Conversion Tracking plugin, and for last i disable WooCommerce, and i show the changes

Comment: Then it's going to be very hard for anyone to guess what the problem is. I would look in the database for "unusual" things like many rows in certain tables first (compare to one of the other sites that has OK performance) - you might find that there are an unusual number of categories or something like that, and get a hint on where to continue. You can also try to make a dump with xdebug (google it if you don't know how), which can often provide hints.

Comment: Oh yes, wp_options table was 5.7mb a week before and know is 78.7 mb. its the bigger table in database.

Comment: Anything called `_transient_*` should be safe to delete - try to `DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_wc%'` and see what happens. If they come back and performance is still slow you need to find out where they come from.

Comment: I'm guessing they're only a symptom though. How many products (and child-products - aka. variations) does the site have (check `wp_posts` table)

Comment: wp_posts is the second bigger table 28mb after wp_option. There are 3865 records.

Comment: I clean the records with DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE '_transient_wc%', but i was cleaned with the same code 2 weeks ago, and they come back.

Comment: Yeah, the transients aren't a problem on their own, in fact they probably have nothing to do with your issues. The "child_has_weight" is part of WC core - there shouldn't be more than one per product though. 3865 are a lot of posts, but doesn't sound extreme enough to be a problem in itself. Do an x-debug dump, I'm out of ideas ;)

Comment: thnx for your time and your ideas...

Comment: A and something for the end, after clean the table wp_options the server load and memory use are back in normal! i suppose until table will full again